# can't cast ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy to text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to save an array to Postgresql DB.  Sounds simple enough.  I am creating an order after a successful stripe payment goes through.

```
#stripe stuff (omitted)
Order.new(
:shipping_price => @order_preview.shipping_price,
:grand_total => @amount,
:cart => @cart,
:items => @cart.line_items
)
@order.save #error here
```

I am getting an error:

```
can't cast ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_LineItem to text
```

If I understand this correctly, rails is telling me it cannot save an array into the text column of my DB.  Why not?

This is what my migration looks like...

```
def change
   add_column :orders, :items, :text, array:true
end
```

I'd appreciate the help...

Thanks

*Edit: Trying to create an array of just ID's now...*

```
    :items => @cart.line_items.map { |l| l.product.id }
```

and that gave me

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch at /charges
ERROR:  column "items" is of type integer[] but expression is of type text at character 249
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Also, when raising an error in the creation process I see the right array

```
items:[1, 2]
```

Of course I need to save quantity with the ID in a hash form but... gotta start at the beginning I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@cart.line_items` is not an Array (it is an ActiveRecord::Relation) and `@cart.line_items.to_a` is not an Array of Strings (it is an Array of LineItems).

You must pass an Array of Strings in order for it to be able to be stored in a `text[]` column. So you either need to determine the appropriate Strings or change the column type to something else.

Comment: What would be column type to save an array like @cart.line_items.to_a?  The idea being I could do @order.items.each do |x| from the view

Comment: Have you looked at 'hstore', it allows you to save json in postgres. A bit like mongodb does.

Comment: @Peege151 probably the most sensible thing would be to store the IDs. But last I checked ActiveRecord doesn’t support associations in array columns, so you’d have to wire everything up yourself.

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your edit: `:items => @cart.line_items.map {|l l.product.id|}` should be `:items => @cart.line_items.map {|l| l.product.id}` (the last pipe removed and put next to the "l").